# Installing gitweb failed: No package gitweb available

Tags: ssh, centos, centos5, git

I have tried installing gitweb via ssh and failed.
Below is what I get.

```
root@server [~]# yum install gitweb
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * rpmforge: ftp-stud.fht-esslingen.de
rpmforge                      | 1.1 kB     00:00     
rpmforge/primary              | 3.8 MB     00:19     
rpmforge                        10502/10502
Excluding Packages in global exclude list
Finished
Setting up Install Process
No package gitweb available.
Nothing to do
```

Anyone has any idea of what else is missing?

Comment: I'm not really sure what your question is asking. If it's not packaged then it's not packaged. Refer to [this](http://repo.or.cz/w/alt-git.git?a=blob_plain;f=gitweb/INSTALL) to install it.

Answer (score 2):

gitweb is available in the EPEL repo http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL.

To add Epel repository to your system open a terminal and as root run:

For RedHat/centos 6

```
rpm -ivh http://mirror.datacenter.by/pub/fedoraproject.org/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
```

For RedHat/centos 5

```
rpm -ivh http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
```

Once you have add the Epel repository install gitweb with the command

```
yum install gitweb-caching.noarch
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if you don't have a yum repository enabled that contains the gitweb package; check the list of repo's in /eyc/yum.repos.d.  Since Git is pretty new, it's possible that you just don't have a recent enough version of CentOS for it to include gitweb in the available packages.

Try the advanced search at http://rpm.pbone.net/ to find where you can get a gitweb package from.